# DNN : communicate with another module

Tags: module, user-controls, dotnetnuke-7

I am new to DNN. So please guide me for my this query.

My requirement is to display one user list page and that will contain one link called 'Edit'. On click of that link it's detail should be displayed.

For this, I have created one module which contains one user control called 'UserList' which is displaying list of users. Now for detail page

1. Should I create new module? If yes then how to communicate with that module from that 'Edit' link?
2. If there is any another way to have both view in same module?

Please guide me what to do in requirement?

Thanks in advance.